# dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libmono-corlib4.5-cil_6.12.0.122-0xamarin1+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb (--unpack)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, monodevelop

I have the following error:

> dpkg: error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libmono-corlib4.5-cil_6.12.0.122-0xamarin1+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb
> (--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll',
> which is also in package libmono-corlib4.5-dll 6.8.0.105+dfsg-3.2
> dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
> Errors were encountered while processing:
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libmono-corlib4.5-cil_6.12.0.122-0xamarin1+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I tried solved using the following commands:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

But return the same error

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

But return

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libmono-cil-dev
 mono-roslyn
 mono-utils
 mono-devel
 mono-complete
 mono-mcs
 mono-xsp4-base
 mono-xsp4

sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/mono* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mono*
```

but return

```
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove mono_crash.12991d684.0.json which isn't installed
```

Is there any way of resolve this mono dependency error, I can uninstall if is need.

Thanks

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you running? Is this server or desktop or WSL?

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop 20

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu called Desktop 20. A Ubuntu version is xx.xx.x

Comment: 20.04.xx then the version

Answer (score 0):

Use `aptitude` and run `aptitude install`. It should detect your package conflicts and give you choices to resolve it.

If you don't have it installed, you may have to manually download it since you usually cant use apt with broken packages/package conflicts.

You'll need to download and install these individually (In order):
`libcwidget4`
`aptitude-common`
`aptitude`

Here's a quick script I made that installs for Ubuntu 21.04
https://gist.github.com/flleeppyy/6a576b3b64edfaf5c16527d53954acbb